# Install ActiveMq admin on my linux Server

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have an application in production which is using Spring integration and activeMq. I need to monitor the activeMq in Prodcution. I cannot install anything with a UI so Jconosle is out. Looks like remote connection may not be allowed either. I need to install a command line uitiliy (like activemq admin) and then start that to monitor the queues. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this. Sorry I am new to this and need some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a combination of the activemq-admin script that comes with the broker, with some sort of monitoring script that is periodically executed to check on whatever you want to check on via the activemq-admin script.  You could probably use a combination of a stand-alone Java process and local JMX connections to accomplish this as well, but the admin script provides access pretty much everything you'd want to monitor and a fairly well documented fashion.

This is as close to command line monitoring as you are going to get with ActiveMQ today.